# Maven release downloading from lib-release instead of lib-snapshot

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, release, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to perform maven release from command line but I am getting below error. I also tried from jenkins job but the same error occurs. I even tried to delete the workspace before the build starts.

```
[INFO] [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[INFO] [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.example:pom:3.0.54 in central (http://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10
```

Ideally maven should download 3.0.54 version from lib-snapshot location and upload it to lib-release but it is trying to download from lib-release where the artifact does not exists. I have mentioned proper details of artifactory in settings.xml

After incrementing the pom version to 3.0.55 I am now getting some different error. Earlier atleast snapshot build was working but now neither release nor snapshot build is working.

```
Parsing POMs
Failed to transfer Could not find metadata com.example.abc:3.0.55-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in snapshots (http://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot)
Failed to transfer Could not find artifact com.exampleabc.pom:3.0.55-SNAPSHOT in snapshots (http://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot)
```

In all the poms I have same version as shown below

```
$ find . -type f -name "pom.xml" -exec sed -n '/3.0.54/p' {} \;

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <version>3.0.54-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Comment: Version `3.0.54` is a release not a SNAPSHOT...and it's downloaded from the release repository instead of the SNAPSHOT repository...

Comment: Yes I understand. That is what my question is. I have mentioned 3.0.54-SNAPSHOT in my pom.xml. But it is still downloading 3.0.54 from lib-release. version 3.0.54 is not there in lib-release. It should be uploaded at the end of the build.

Comment: That's obviously not the case cause the output says something different. Furthermore a pom file here would help...

Comment: @khmarbaise, the pom file is pretty big and I will have to change a lot of thing. Do you need any specific settings?

Answer (score 0):

Your error says

```
Could not find artifact com.example:pom:3.0.54
```

This means that at some point you referenced `3.0.54` instead of `3.0.54-SNAPSHOT`. Maybe you are looking at a wrong branch or revision, maybe you mixed up projects.

Comment: After incrementing pom version i am getting different error. I have updated my question

Comment: Why do you increase the version? `3.0.55-SNAPSHOT` probably does not exist. You need to solve your original problem, namely: Somewhere you set the version to `3.0.54` instead `3.0.54-SNAPSHOT`. You need to find that point.

Comment: Like I shown in the question I fired find command to find all the pom.xml files and grepped the version but did not find anything without SNAPSHOT.

Comment: I understand 3.0.55-SNAPSHOT does not exists and that is why it is giving the error. But in my previous previous build I saw it normally finds the metadata file. Previously after incrementing the pom version I was to fix this type of issues

Comment: I cannot really follow you. Your error is that you reference `com.example:pom:3.0.54` but it is not there. So try to fix that.

Comment: Then you need to find the place where you reference `com.example:pom:3.0.54`. It may also be possible that your maven commands contain a call to a `versions` plugin.

Comment: I asked the developers to verify it from their side as well but they are saying all the poms are using SNAPSHOT and they are not using any version plugin.